# Pinterest Access Token Stopped

Tags: pinterest

This morning my apps stopped working. I have 30,000 users who uses my app everyday. I query my pins on Pinterest to my app  using access token.
When I noticed the error I quickly tried Pinterest documentation but the access token page is gone.

I have a collaborator for my app but is still not showing the authorize button. What do I do.

Comment: Did you resolve this? And how? I have the same problem as of two weeks ago.

Comment: No. I had to update my app and look for another way

Comment: What was the other way if you don't mind me asking?

Comment: I asked for the same problem but people are downvoting rather than answering, and am supporting you - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50150697/generate-pinterest-access-token-dynamically-with-php-api